# Which is better for storing Meta-description of categories , php var or mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, performance

i am working on image site where, images belongs to the specific categories,

there are 70+ category types/name (i.e. books,trees,people,watches,cars,mobiles etc) as of now and will be near about 80-90 categories in near future , and each category has meta description, meta keywords , title specific to that category.

my question is where should i store this data ?

1. in php using 3-4 types of array and then using array lookup to
   find and show the meta data specific to that directory ?

e.g.

```
$meta_description = array('books' => 'books meta description', 'trees' => 'trees meta description')
```

and then doing

```
if(isset($meta_description[$_GET['category']])){
echo $meta_description[$_GET['category']]);
}
```

---

2. in MySQL db table and then doing mysql query on each page load
   for getting meta description, title data from db ?

e.g.

table

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cat_name   | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| title      | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| metakw     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| metadesc   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| record_num | tinyint(2)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and then getting info using mysql query on each page load.

i am looking for high performance as there are 20+ million records in the main table and there are already lots of mysql queries are fired every second, so i am lloking to lower the mysql burden .

Answer (score 1):

Good practice is to keep as much cached as possible, therefore no. 1 is much better choice (as long as categories do not have to be configurable by user). However if you need to make it configurable then you should keep in the database and cache it using i.e. memcached http://www.memcached.org/

Comment: categories are fixed. and cant be configurable by users. yes, use of memcached are next move i am planning to implement, wont this make php use more memory if i go with option 1 ?

Comment: Then there is no doubt that solution no 1 is better choice.

Comment: Well, it's hardcoded then and he will need to edit the php file for every change of a categorie or if he adds a new one. Better practice would be using a MySQL table and then cache the data as long as there is no update in a file as serialized or json array.

Comment: You are right, but it requires more overhead, more coding and more testing :-).

Comment: Are you saying more coding is a bad thing? :)